# Regex to split BBCode into pieces

Tags: ruby, regex, split, bbcode

I have this:

```
str = "some html code [img]......[/img] some html code [img]......[/img]"
```

and I want to get this:

```
["[img]......[/img]","[img]......[/img]"]
```

Comment: regex isn't exactly the best of choices for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> str = "some html code [img]......[/img] some html \
code [img]......[/img]"
"some html code [img]......[/img] some html code [img]......[/img]"
irb(main):002:0> str.scan(/\[img\].*?\[\/img\]/)
["[img]......[/img]", "[img]......[/img]"]
```

Keep in mind that this is a very specific answer that is based on your exact question. Change `str` by, say, adding *an image tag within an image tag*, and **[all Hell will break loose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)**.

Answer (score 46):

Please don't use BBCode. It's *evil*.

> BBCode came to life when developers
>   were too lazy to parse HTML correctly
>   and decided to invent their own markup
>   language. As with all products of
>   laziness, the result is completely
>   inconsistent, unstandardized, and
>   widely adopted.

Try to use a user-friendlier markup language, like [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (that's what Stack Overflow uses) or [Textile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_(markup_language)).
Both of them have parsers for Ruby:

- [Maruku](http://github.com/nex3/maruku) for Markdown
- [RedCloth](http://redcloth.org/) for Textile

---

If you still don't want to heed to my advice and choose to go with BBCode, don't reinvent the wheel and use a [BBCode parser](http://code.google.com/p/ruby-bbcode/). To answer your question directly, there is the least desirable option: use regex.

```
/\[img\].*?\[\/img\]/
```

As seen on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/4WtcTTgx4j). Although I would use `/\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/`, so it will extract the contents inside the `img` tags. Note that this is fairly fragile and will break if there are nested `img` tags. Hence, the advice to use a parser.

Comment: +1 just for the quote. although it's a parser, not an interpreter.

Comment: @sre I knew I couldn't be the *only* one who hated BBCode with a passion.

Comment: bbcode is an ill-conceived, badly-designed, and generally poorly-implemented html knock-off. its sole redeeming quality is that it tends to be shorter than html. and of course, that's not hard to do.

Comment: +1 BBCode is actually HTML with square brackets and synonyms.

Comment: `BBCode came to life when developers were too lazy to parse HTML correctly and decided to invent their own markup language.` It is not a solid argument but rather a subjective opinion. BBcodes have been there for a long time and are still used on forums. People know them. Instead, what in the world is Textile? I haven't heard of it. And I'm sure most people as well. Why reinvent a new bicycle if the old one is firmly doing its job?

Comment: What's the source of the quote?

Answer (score 4):

There is a [ruby BBCODE parser](http://code.google.com/p/ruby-bbcode/) at Google Code.

Don't use regex for this.

Comment: @square:: Hm, my reading is that with a parser you can create any output you like, be it HTML or a simple array. This parser is a suggestion only, there are others, I'm sure. Key point is: Your time is better spent figuring out how to use a parser for this than trying to do it with regex. Even if it seems the other way around at first.

Answer (score -1):

```
str = "some html code [img]......[/img] some html code [img]......[/img]"
p str.split("[/img]").each{|x|x.sub!(/.*\[img\]/,"")}
```