# How do you get multiple args in a PEAR BBCODE Parser?

Tags: php, html, image, pear, bbcode

Currently I am parsing my text using the PHP5 PEAR BBCode parser. Now I am looking into my img tag and realise I don't know how to specify 3 args. 
This is the format of the input:

```
[img src="" title="" alt=""]
```

And what I want to get out:

```
<img src="" title="" alt="">
```

I am currently using this code but I cannot access multiple arguments-

```
    'img'=>      array('type'=>BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG,
                'open_tag'=>'<img src="', 'close_tag'=>'" />',
                'childs'=>''),
```

Comment: It looks like you are using PECL version of BBcode parser (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php), not PEAR one (http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_BBCodeParser/)

Comment: Can we please vanquish the [evil that BBcode is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788959/regex-to-split-bbcode-into-pieces/3792262#3792262)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BBcode does not have the concept of multiple attributes - you cannot do what you want.

Only single, unnamed attributes are supported:

```
[url=http://example.org]name[/url]
```