# sql developer mysql to oracle migration

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I successfuly migrate mysql to oracle. But the only problem is case sensitive on table name and fieldname.Some pages in web said go to tools and option in sql developer  and tick  the ansi but i cannot find it.
On oracle website forum said it part of migration . 
Anybody had new version of sql developer and migrate from mysql  ?

E.g

calendarColor become CALENDARCOLOR

Comment: Please show us the **real** SQL statements that you are running. Ideally show use the CREATE TABLE statement as well (just copy that CREATE table from SQL Developer it is displayed there)

Comment: `PROMPT Creating Table calendarcolor ...
CREATE TABLE calendarcolor (
  calendarColorId NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL
);


PROMPT Creating Primary Key Constraint PRIMARY_3 on table calendarcolor ... 
ALTER TABLE calendarcolor
ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY_3 PRIMARY KEY
(
  calendarColorId
)
ENABLE
;`

Comment: seem  generate code is not uppercase weird.. have to check back on the generated code

Comment: If no quotes are used in the CREATE TABLE, then the table is stored in uppercase internally and you don't need to use quotes anywhere

Comment: hope there a way to escape it or quote.. Is the best pratice.. since mysql using `  and mssql using [] and oracle using " for those weird or special name

Comment: Simply don't use any quoting ever.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see how this is a problem. Since Oracle's objects are case-insensitive by default, you can continue to query them using `SELECT * FROM calendarColor`.

If you *need* them to be case sensitive, use quotes, like:

```
CREATE TABLE "calendarColor" ( ... );

SELECT * FROM TABLE "calendarColor";
```

See also: [Schema Object Names and Qualifiers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm)

Comment: [quote]Error starting at line 1 in command:
select * from "calendarColor"
Error at Command Line:1 Column:14
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:[/quote]

Comment: If you created the table without using quotes (ie: case-insensitive), you *have* to refer to it without quotes (or if you do use quotes, use all uppercase letters). Also please don't use [BBCode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788959/regex-to-split-bbcode-into-pieces/3792262#3792262) here. It's fugly and SO doesn't support it.

Comment: hmm.. i not generate the code. it generate by sql developer.. Hmm.. seem you don't used it..better not answer...

Answer (score 1):

If the table was created using

```
CREATE TABLE calendarcolor ( calendarColorId NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL );
```

then the table name is stored in uppercase internally. When you run a statement like this:

```
select * from "calendarColor"
```

then you are telling Oracle: *The table name should be treated case-sensitive* but as there is not table named `calenderColor`, only one named `CALENDARCOLOR` your statement fails.

The fix is very easy: remove the quotes and change the select to

```
select * from calendarColor
```