# Remove nested bbcode quotes in Python?

Tags: python, bbcode

I tried searching for this and only found PHP answers.  I'm using Python on Google App Engine and am trying to remove nested quotes.

For example:

```
[quote user2]
[quote user1]Hello[/quote]
World
[/quote]
```

I would like to run something to just get the outer most quote.

```
[quote user2]World[/quote]
```

Comment: -1: doesn't show research effort. What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not here to do all your work for you.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: I think you're being too harsh

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788959/regex-to-split-bbcode-into-pieces/3792262#3792262

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you just want the quotes, or the whole input with nested quotes removed.  This pyparsing sample does both:

```
stuff = """
Other stuff
[quote user2] 
[quote user1]Hello[/quote] 
World 
[/quote] 
Other stuff after the stuff
"""

from pyparsing import (Word, printables, originalTextFor, Literal, OneOrMore, 
    ZeroOrMore, Forward, Suppress)

# prototype username
username = Word(printables, excludeChars=']')

# BBCODE quote tags
openQuote = originalTextFor(Literal("[") + "quote" + username + "]")
closeQuote = Literal("[/quote]")

# use negative lookahead to not include BBCODE quote tags in tbe body of the quote
contentWord = ~(openQuote | closeQuote) + (Word(printables,excludeChars='[') | '[')
content = originalTextFor(OneOrMore(contentWord))

# define recursive definition of quote, suppressing any nested quotes
quotes = Forward()
quotes << ( openQuote + ZeroOrMore( Suppress(quotes) | content ) + closeQuote )

# put separate tokens back together
quotes.setParseAction(lambda t : '\n'.join(t))

# quote extractor
for q in quotes.searchString(stuff):
    print q[0]

# nested quote stripper
print quotes.transformString(stuff)
```

Prints:

```
[quote user2]
World
[/quote]

Other stuff
[quote user2]
World
[/quote] 
Other stuff after the stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find and use a real BBCode parser in Python. Googling brings up some hits - for example [this one](http://www.willmcgugan.com/blog/tech/2007/3/10/bbcode-python-module/), and [this one](http://www.codigomanso.com/en/2010/09/bbcodeutils-bbcode-parser-and-bbcode-to-html-for-python/).

Comment: Oh, I'm actually using the first one!  But when I tested it, the quotes kept going and going.  I didn't think that maybe it was able to address this issue, I'll check it out.