# Match "123. some string" into two variables

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I split the following string into two variables with regex? Sometimes the space from the song position to the title is missing e.g `2.Culture Beat – Mr. Vain`

```
2.  Culture Beat – Mr. Vain
```

result I am looking for:

```
pos = 2
title = Culture Beat – Mr. Vain
```

Comment: You want to match a series of 1 or more digits, a literal period, a series of 0 or more spaces, and then all remaining characters. You should be able to break down this problem and figure it out. This is a very trivial regular expression.

Comment: Could you include the regex you have tried so far?

Comment: Was playing around with the regex for a few hours without getting nowhere. Both examples below works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to split BBCode into pieces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788959/regex-to-split-bbcode-into-pieces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
(full, pos, title) =  your_string.match(/(\d+)\.\s*(.*)/).to_a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
(\d+?)\.\s*(.*)
```

http://rubular.com/r/gV4MimUFyq

It returns two capture groups, one for the number and one for the title.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = "2.  Culture Beat – Mr. Vain"

# split the string into an array, dividing by point and 0 to n spaces
pos, title = s.split(/(?!\d+)\.\s*/)

# coerce the position to an integer
pos = pos.to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

One option with capture groups:

```
match = "2. Culture Beat - Mr. Vain".match(/(?<position>\d+)\.\s*(?<title>.*)/)

position = match['position']
title = match['title']

p "Position: #{ position }; Title: '#{ title }'"
# => "Position: 2; Title: 'Culture Beat - Mr. Vain'"
```